# How can I install the OracleDB NPM package on a Heroku NodeJS server?

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm, node-oracledb

I have a NodeJS server running on Heroku and I'm trying to install the oracledb package(https://www.npmjs.com/package/oracledb) to my server's node_modules when pushing to Heroku.

When pushing to Heroku I am getting this error when the oracledb package is attempted to be installed: "node-oracledb ERR! Error: Cannot find Oracle library libclntsh.so". The full error output I am getting from the Heroku push can be seen here: https://gist.github.com/AkyunaAkish/89a4283cc2da32e26fece617d4138ce0

I tried following this repo's readme to install addons that I thought would help but that didn't seem to make a difference: https://github.com/MichaelBuhler/heroku-buildpack-nodejs-oracledb

I then went to the node-oracledb repository and attempted to follow their instructions for installing oracledb on Linux(by using Heroku run bash and then running the commands) although that didn't work because yum is not available and the file system is read-only; https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/INSTALL.md#instlinux

I don't need to host an oracledb instance in my heroku environment, I just need to install the package into my node_modules in order to use my database-driver to connect to a remote oracledb being hosted elsewhere.

Any suggestions as to how to setup the environment properly for my needs would be appreciated, thanks.

`FYI`: I asked Heroku support and was told it's not an issue that falls within the nature of the Heroku Support policy so here I am.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had problems trying to install oracledb on my Heroku too with the same approach. I forked that and changed some things, including how the script got the instantclient libs and have success installing now. Please check my fork here: https://github.com/pupostd/heroku-buildpack-nodejs-oracledb.git

Comment: This worked for me thanks. I followed your updated instructions in the readme. I also had to add a Procfile containing: "web: node ./server/init.js" in order for the server to properly run after adding the buildpack. For some reason the new version of oracledb didn't run properly for me so I updated the package-lock.json to use version 1.13.1 instead of 2+.

Comment: If node-oracledb v2's pre-built binaries are unusable for some reason, you can always build from source code like in the v1 days by using 'oracle/node-oracledb#v2.0.15' as your package.json dependency.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't need to host an oracledb instance in my heroku environment

node-oracledb (installed via npm as oracledb) is just a driver, not a database.

> I tried following this repo's readme to install addons that I thought would help but that didn't seem to make a difference

What did you try (exactly) and what happened (if errors, which ones)?

> yum is not available and the file system is read-only

Are you sure this is true? Can you point to doc? You need to get the dependencies in place somehow. The author of the "heroku-buildpack-nodejs-oracledb" you pointed to seems to suggest that using the Heroku CLI with buildpacks can be used as a workaround.

Keep in mind that if use that buildpack you're trusting its author's mirror for the Oracle dependencies. I suggest you download the dependencies and securely place them in some object storage of your own, then point to that.

Comment: You are correct that oracledb is just a driver, that driver is what I'm trying to install. 

For this repo: https://github.com/MichaelBuhler/heroku-buildpack-nodejs-oracledb I ran the buildpack commands and created the Aptfile with the suggested file content. After adding those build packs and that file to my heroku project, when pushing my code, the same error I showed in my github gist happened again, so there was no improvement. 

When trying to use yum commands to get the oracle client yum was not a command, also trying to create new directories in heroku bash caused a read-only error.

Comment: I'll look into downloading the dependencies in a secure place and point to them like you said probably with environment variables.

Comment: The first build pack used is heroku-buildpack-apt. apt is an alternative to yum for certain Linux distros. You may need to use that to install libaio. The second build pack, heroku-buildpack-nodejs-oracledb, is the one you need to customize with your own files.